# Extract JSON with different values to repeated id column in pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas, concatenation

I have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':['0001', '0001'],
                   'vat_countries': [{'vat': 21, 'country': 'ES'}, 
                                     {'vat': 23, 'country': 'GR'}]
                   })

id        vat_countries
0001     {'vat': 21, 'country': 'ES'}
0001     {'vat': 23, 'country': 'GR'}
```

What I want to get is:

```
id   vat  country
0001  21    'ES'
0001  23    'GR'
```

Reading other SO questions I got the following code:

```
df = df.drop('vat_countries', 1).assign(**pd.DataFrame(list_df['vat_countries'].values.tolist()))
```

However, that gives me:

```
id   vat  country
    0001  21    'ES'
    0001  21    'ES'
```

which is wrong.

I have been able to get the results that I want using:

```
c = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(df[column].values.tolist()), 
               df.drop(column, 1).reset_index()], 
              axis=1, ignore_index=True)
```

But this requires to manually type the column names. Otherwise, the column names are 0, 1, 2, 3...

Is there any way I get my desired output while conserving the name of the columns?
Thanks

EDIT: Trying BEN_YO solution. I have this
[image]
And after the code I get this
[image]
Everything gets duplicated twice

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try with `pop` fix your code

```
df.join(pd.DataFrame(df.pop('vat_countries').tolist(),index=df.index))
Out[300]: 
     id  vat country
0  0001   21      ES
1  0001   23      GR
```

Comment: In my real example that gives me everything duplicated. See the question edited for more details

Comment: @JavierLópezTomás I am using you sample data , if this does not work for real data ,please find the different between your sample data and real data, and update sample data in your question

Comment: Yep, I got it work in my sample data. I have edited the question to show an example. I'll try to make a sample data that have the same error as the real with your answer. In the meantime, would you have any idea taking a look at the tables?

Comment: @JavierLópezTomás df=df.reset_index(drop=True), before running above solution ~

Answer (score 1):

You could access the individual values using `string methods` :

```
df["vat"] = df.vat_countries.str["vat"]
df["country"] = df.vat_countries.str["country"]
df      

    id         vat_countries               vat  country
0   0001    {'vat': 21, 'country': 'ES'}    21  ES
1   0001    {'vat': 23, 'country': 'GR'}    23  GR
```

Answer (score 0):

I would apply `pd.Series` at columns with `dict`s and `join` result with original, i.e.:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':['0001', '0001'], 'vat_countries': [{'vat': 21, 'country': 'ES'}, {'vat': 23, 'country': 'GR'}]})
final_df = df.join(df.vat_countries.apply(pd.Series))
print(final_df)
```

Output:

```
     id                 vat_countries  vat country
0  0001  {'vat': 21, 'country': 'ES'}   21      ES
1  0001  {'vat': 23, 'country': 'GR'}   23      GR
```

As you can see vat_countires was left, if you wish to jettison it you might simply `drop` it.